# How to read $_GET variables with (mod rewrite powered) nice URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm using nice URLs the first time and I can't quite find out why I can't read my oAuth responses from my script.

So this is my setup:

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

I have a script that uses googles oAuth system to log in a user. This script sends the user to the google api page where they can allow my website to read their email adress and then send the user right back to my site with lots of $_GET variables.

I tell google to send it to

```
http://mywebsite/login/google/response
```

and it does that..

The problem is that google sends the result in the normal GET format like this:

```
http://mywebsite/login/google/response/?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.ne[..]
```

and my script can't read it..

Is there any way to read $_GET variables when they mix with nice URLs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (query string append) to your flags.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Then your `$_GET` will contain the correct values.