# How do I parse GET style parameters when the Yii urlManager has urlFormat set to 'path'?

Tags: url, yii

My application is written to make use of Yii clean urls. The urlManager has urlFormat set to path, so the application expects parameters in the form "/home/login/12".

My problem is that I am using a third-party API class that expects callbacks in the form "/api/login?user_id=12&foo=234234&bar=xyzzy". These parameters are not available in $_GET because Yii doesn't interpret them as separate parameters.

How do I tell the urlManager to use a **get** urlFormat for this one controller?

UPDATE:

My configuration options for the urlManager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        // Other paths
        '/' => 'home/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

My test query strings:

```
http://localhost/testcontroller/testaction?id=x&blah=y
http://localhost/testcontroller/testaction/?id=x&blah=y
```

I'm using Yii version 1.1.10.r3566.

Comment: I think you misunderstood yii urlManger. The extra parameters that are not specified in url rules are available in `$_GET`. Just do a `print_r($_GET)` in the controller/view with some xtra parameters on the url

Comment: I have tried, and the only thing in $_GET is "req".

Comment: there is no GET param for "req" in your test url. From where that came from?

Comment: It comes from Yii presumably, when it parses the request. The extra parameters that are not specified in the url rules don't exist in $_GET. I *have* tested this. I did a print_r($_GET), but the only thing it contains is a single variable called "req". It appears to contain the request path, but that's it.

Comment: And are you getting the correct $_GET values when `urlFormat` is not set to `path` ?

Comment: Indeed, although I need to change the url to: `http://localhost/?r=testcontroller&blah=X&q=yyy`

Comment: I dint get whats going on. Btw if you are using any apache `RewriteCond` url rewriting this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555589/how-to-read-get-variables-with-mod-rewrite-powered-nice-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [dInGd0nG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362777/dingd0ng), the problem existed in our rewriting rules.

They were this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?req=$1
```

When they should have been this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed. I was using Nginx and had the same problem. It turns out that my original nginx setup is wrong:

```
    location / {
            # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$uri;
    }
```

I changed it to the following and params shows up.

```
    location / {
            # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$uri&$args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"How do I tell the urlManager to use a get urlFormat for this one controller?"

Your best option is probably going to be overriding the UrlManager and createUrl / parseUrl functions so that you can handle this one route in your own custom manner.

Comment: I am hoping a more elegant solution exists. The problem looks so trivial. Why does it require such a big hammer?